# butterknife @OnClick inside ViewHolder in CustomAdapter

Tags: android, onclick, custom-adapter, butterknife

I'm currently learning butterknife, and I need to bind specific @OnClicks on different views generated by my customer adapter. How do I go about with this?

I've seen an answer in one of the questions here saying that he uses '@onclick' inside the 'ViewHolder'. I'm not sure how to implement this exactly. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Imagine you have a ViewHolder like this.

```
static class ViewHolder {

    @InjectView(R.id.user_name)
    TextView userName;

    @InjectView(R.id.user_title)
    TextView userTitle;


    public ViewHolder(View view) {
        ButterKnife.inject(this, view);
    }

}
```

You can bind events in your adapters getView method for each view in your holder.

```
 @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView != null) {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    } else {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(
                R.layout.your_row_layout, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }

   holder.userName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Your stuff here
        }
    });


    holder.userTitle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           //Your stuff here  
        }
    });

    return convertView;

}
```

Comment: +1 for making ViewHolder final and actually calling it ViewHolder.  +1 for making the ViewHolder Class static.  Finally, +1 for using != null to get the smaller block of if-logic up top and out of the way.  Never considered doing the the if-logic that way.  I'll be updating my code ;) I wish more SO answers were like this.  Well done @Ugur.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! This is exactly what I needed! Marked as answer. (:

Answer (score 3):

As @Ugur has suggested you would initiate your ViewHolder using butterknife. You can add an on click listener to a view by doing this as an example for the userName View:

```
@OnClick(R.id.user_name)
public void clickedUserName(SocialEyeTextView userName)
{
    //Do something with user name
}
```

Comment: Hi. Is this also possible?

@OnClick(R.id.user_name)
public void clickedUserName(SocialEyeTextView userTitle)
{
    if(userTItle.text == 'john')
    {
         // something
    }
}

Or something similar?

Comment: Basically click on the name, then check title

Comment: This is not gonna work on a ViewHolder view element. You need to set the click listener as in @Ugur answer.

Comment: Exactly the bug I was encountering. Because each ViewHolder instance will have a different position.

Answer (score 1):

I have this `ViewHolder`..

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        @Bind(R.id.item_tipo_evento_estado_text) TextView text;
        @Bind(R.id.item_text_radiobutton_check) AppCompatCheckBox checkBox;
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
        }

        @OnClick(R.id.btnCheck)
        public void onCheck() {
            Log.d("ViewHolder", "position ->" + getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }
```

ok my `R.id.btnCheck` is my id of `LinearLayout` content all `Views`

Answer (score 0):

write this code in `ViewHolder` class

```
static class ViewHolder {
    public int getPosition;

    @Nullable
    @Bind(R.id.txt_title_name)
    TextView txtTitle;   

 public ViewHolder(View view) {
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
    }


    @OnClick(R.id.btn_download)
    public void onCheck() {
        Log.d("ViewHolder", "position ->" + getPosition);
    }
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

holder.getPosition = position;
}
```

Comment: What is this and how are the two related?